# Why has replacing ng-select with a custom directive caused $http requests not to be sent every other time

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

*edit I've now fixed the bug by using `ng-click` in the directive's template, but I'm still interested to know what `ng-click` does that's different to `element.bind` and why it's important*

I did have a ng-select box to update my model

`<td><select
  ng-model="tune.dummyStandard"
  ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in dropdowns.playback"
  ng-change="update()" >
  <option value="">-- rate performance --</option>
</select></td>`

At the end of a long validation process, it created a new `$http` request (via `$resource.$update`) and saved the record.

I've now changed to use a custom directive

`<td j-performance-rater data-tune="tune"></td>`

which attaches the following listener (the actual listener is a little more complicated but I've checked quite rigorously that it always fires `tune.resource.$update` as expected)

```
element.bind('click', function (ev) {

   // code for validation and setting of model props

   tune.resource.$update();

});
```

Now odd-numbered clicks create the `$http` object but don't send, and the even-numbered clicks send the previously created `$http` object and create and successfully send a new one. This happens consistently even when the clicks are on different instances of the directive. I've tried playing around with `$digest` and `$apply` on the scope but they don't have any impact (and I'm not sure if they should as `$http` seems to me like it should behave independently of the digest cycle).

Can anyone think what the problem might be?

### Full directive code

```
directives.directive('jPerformanceRater', function () {
    return {
    // transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '/views/directives/performance-rater.html',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var tune = scope[attrs.tune || 'tune'];

                scope.tune = tune.tune;
                element.bind('click', function (ev) {
                    ev.cancelBubble = true;
                    var btn = ev.target.className.indexOf('icon') > -1 ? ev.target.parentNode : ev.target;

                    if (btn.className.indexOf('btn')  === -1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    tune.dummyStandard = +btn.textContent;
                    tune.update(); // most of the validation happens in here and then it calls resource.$update()

                });
                element.addClass('performance-rater');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

### And the template

```
<span class="btn btn-small" ng-repeat="rating in dropdowns.playback" type="checkbox"
   title="{{rating.label}}">{{rating.value}}<i class="icon icon-star{{rating.value == 0 ? '-empty' : ''}}"></i></span>
```

Comment: not totally clear what issue is, but important to know that if you change a scope object within external (non angular) code like a click handler that you change scope using `$apply` so angular is aware of the modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing :

```
element.bind('click', function (ev) {
  tune.resource.$update();
});
```

to:

```
element.bind('click', function (ev) {
  scope.$apply(function(){
     tune.resource.$update();
  });
});
```

should do the trick.
Diference between `bind('click')` and `ng-click` is that `ng-click` triggers angular `$digest` cycle whereas `bind('click')` does not.
Any `$http` or `$resource` requests trigger request to server only when invoked within angular `$digest` cycle (internal angular event loop cycle). So in your case you invoked `resource.update` but outside angular `$digest` cycle, so request to server wasn't made but only 'scheduled' until next time angular event loop was triggered (for example when ng-change was executed) and request to server was initiated.

Comment: Great explanantion. Has increased my understanding of angular no end